# Realm & Kotlin: DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java -> error: unreachable statement

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm working with Kotlin and Realm. When I try to build my project that contains both Java and Kotlin files, I get the following error in  `DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java`:

```
 error: unreachable statement
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
In your (Project: ProjectName) `gradle.build` file update the version of Realm. With version 3.3.0 it works good:

```
dependencies {
     ...
     classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.3.0'
     ...
}
```

**Only if this doesn't fix the problem**, try the options below:

---

**Option 1:**
In your Module:app `gradle.build` change the order of Kotlin and Realm plugins.

From this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

To this:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

---

**Option 2:** In your build.sript, if you have:

```
compileOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

Change it to `false`:

```
compileOptions {
    incremental false
}
```

Comment: `realm-android` should be **after** `kotlin-android`, as far as I know anyways. In fact, typically it is in order `kotlin-android`, then `kotlin-kapt`, then `realm-android`.... I have also seen `kapt { generateStubs = true }` although I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: With 'realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.0' if Realm is after Kotlin you get 'error: unreachable statement' in DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java

Comment: ah yeah, because `kapt` support was added in 2.2.0 see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#220-2016-11-12