# IncompatibleClassChangeError when called "realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate({RealmModel})"

Tags: android, database, realm

when i call "realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate({RealmObject})", app crashes on lower API(21-25). No problem in version API-25 and above. Logcat output :

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
        at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:131)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1815)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:1199)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.MainActivity.DataFetched$lambda-10(MainActivity.kt:826)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$fX_wkxDWKFkFuw4LXNz0m5YzJyo(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.execute(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1604)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.MainActivity.DataFetched(MainActivity.kt:823)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.NetworkOperations.getData.ExecuteNetWorkCall$lambda-0(getData.kt:111)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.NetworkOperations.getData.$r8$lambda$Va8-rJSbrmVyGMKSedsNwZR74V8(getData.kt)
        at com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.NetworkOperations.getData$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onResponse(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:100)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

i use in top-level gradle;

> classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.10.1"

I have no idea for the solution. I added try-catch block for now. I suspect ProGuard. but, for now i couldn't find the solution

Comment: Here is solution you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44176024/1343788

Comment: This is a little confusing `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate({RealmModel})` - do you literally mean `RealmModel` or `someModel.self` or is it a Realm object? Along with that, do the objects have primary keys? Posting an error here on SO isn't really helpful because it could be caused by a number of things. Can you post the code that's thowing the error? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you are right. sorry @Jay. this is RealmObject. I edited

Comment: I tried @MehulKabaria's solution. but not working for me